# can a doctors office call you months after a procedure and say oh, we mis-billed you, you owe $600 more?

Tags: billing

Can the CEO of a dentists office call you up and say that their clerk billed me wrong and I owe an additional $600.00 and that I should be happy it wasn't for thousands like other patients?

Comment: If you actually owe then the money, heck yes.

Comment: Do dentist offices have CEOs?

Comment: This is a legal question, please include information about where you are located.

Answer (score 1):

The dentists office can call you and claim that you owe them more money but if there is any concern of the legality of their claim I would recommend consulting an attorney before paying.

If you actually do owe the money, however, then yes you will likely need to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they can. Up to six years in many countries. There can be consequences. If you went to the dentist three years ago, were happy with the bill and returned every six months, and the dentist informs you that your six $200 bills should have each been $1,200 then it is obvious that you would have looked for another dentist if the first bill had been correct; in that case you have a very good reason to refuse to pay the difference on the other five bills.

(That's if you were not aware that the bill was wrong. If every time he fixed your teeth and the bill says "examining your teeth" which you would expect to be a lot cheaper, then maybe you should have known that the bill was wrong. Just an example).

Answer (score 0):

Careful, here.  The last time we got a bill from the doctor's office because they made a billing mistake it turns out the bill was a mistake.  Before you pay anything go through the list of charges and payments and make sure it's accurate.  (In our case she went to an appointment and was then told there was no reason for the doctor to see her that day.  Several months later a bill for the visit showed up--except they hadn't kept straight what payment was for what visit so it took some digging to figure out what had happened.